# Right align 3 div's to the right of the page

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to right align 3 div boxes in the order **signin_box - signin_btn - signin_opt**. My current code is swapping **signin_opt** with **signin_box**. I know I can just swap the placement in the HTML code but I want to learn how to float the correct way.

```
.container {
    border-top: solid #27A7DF 3px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 43px;
    width: 100%
}
.signin_box {
    height: 42px;
    width: 275px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #323232
}
.signin_btn {
    height: 42px;
    width: 72px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #000
}
.signin_opt {
    height: 42px;
    width: 135px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #323232
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="signin_box"></div>
    <div class="signin_btn"></div>
    <div class="signin_opt"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using float the order matters. Try using like so:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="signin_opt"></div> 
    <div class="signin_btn"></div> 
    <div class="signin_box"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of that, but wanted to do it the correct way too keep the code readable and in order.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do it "right". You see, when dealing with floats, the first element is pushed rightmost, then the second element, and so forth. That's why if you want a specific order on the scrren, say `1 - 2 - 3`, you have to place in the HTML in reverse order `3 - 2 - 1`.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll just swap the position cause it seems like the only other option would be to add another div another container to float the 3 boxes collectively to the right. And that would just be unnecessary coding if I did that.

Answer (score 1):

When you float siblings to the right, the elements first specified in the HTML are pushed farthest right. To keep the elements in the order specified by the HTML, you need to float the container to the right and its children to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the `clear: right;` CSS attribute.

Fiddle: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YZBjt/)

Example:

```
.signin_box {
    height: 42px;
    width: 275px;
    float: right;
    background-color: yellow;
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: If you add a `clear:right` you'll add only a second line, changing the desired output of the O.P.

Comment: the boxes need to stay to the right of each other like the http://jsfiddle.net/YZBjt/2/ but _opt and _box need to swap places